# Extract native interface from Puppeteer browser/page context

Tags: javascript, jestjs, puppeteer

Is it possible to retrieve a native interface from the Browser or Page instance in order to check if an object is an `instanceof` this interface?

For instance, in a jest testing context (where for some reasons CanvasRenderingContext2D isn't available since it is a Node context and not a JSDOM or an other emulation of browser APIs):

```
it("should create an instance of CanvasRenderingContext2D", async () => {
  expect.assertions(1);

  const context = await page.evaluate(() => {
    return document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d");
  });

  // Could a JSHandle be used somehow?
  const CanvasRenderingContext2DInterface = await page.evaluateHandle(() => CanvasRenderingContext2D);

  expect(context).toBeInstanceOf(CanvasRenderingContext2DInterface);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instance check should be evaluated in the Puppeteer browser/page directly otherwise the execution contexts are different.

```
it("should create an instance of CanvasRenderingContext2D", async () => {
  expect.assertions(1);

  const isInstanceOfCanvasRenderingContext2D = await page.evaluate(
    () =>
      document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d") instanceof CanvasRenderingContext2D
  );
  expect(isInstanceOfCanvasRenderingContext2D).toBeTruthy();
});
```